# I want as small as possible code for creating a database and a table and storing a record then displaying all in qml cascade (BlackBerry)if possible

Tags: qt, blackberry, qml, cascade

I want as small as possible code for creating a database and a table and storing a record then displaying all in Qml cascade (BlackBerry)if possible.  please please explain in layman's terms. Thank you in advance

Comment: You haven't demonstrated any effort to research the problem or attempt to solve it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using SQLite for database. These are very lightweight and easy to set up.

Then Qt provides a QAbstractItemModel-derived class that can turn your database into a model with the absolute minimum code, I dont recall the name but its there, google should help you.

You can expose this class to qml and use as a model for you table directly.

You can get back to me if you need help.

Comment: Thank you "Teimpz" for your response.